# Relation between worst case and average case running time of an algorithm

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

Let's say A(n) is the average running time of an algorithm and W(n) is the worst. Is it correct to say that

```
A(n) = O(W(n))
```

is always true?

Comment: Detail: `A(n)` is actually an *element* of `O(W(n))`.

Comment: Yep.. understand that part..hope it is implied..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Big O notation is kind of tricky, since it only defines an upper bound to the execution time of a given algorithm.

What this means is, if `f(x) = O(g(x))` then for every other function `h(x)` such that `g(x) < h(x)` you'll have `f(x) = O(h(x))` . The problem is, are those over extimated execution times usefull? and the clear answer is not at all. What you usually whant is the "smallest"
 upper bound you can get, but this is not strictly required in the definition, so you can play around with it.

You can get some stricter bound using the other notations, such as the Big Theta, as you can read [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations).

So, the answer to your question is yes, `A(n) = O(W(n))`, but that doesn't give any usefull information on the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

If you're mentioning A(n) and W(n) are functions - then, yes, you can do such statement in common case - it is because big-o [formal definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition).

Note, that in terms on [big-o](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) there's no sense to act such way - since it makes understanding of the real complexity worse. (In general, three cases - worst, average, best - are present exactly to show complexity more clear)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is not a mistake to say so.
People use asymptotic notation to convey the growth of running time on specific cases in terms of input sizes.To compare the average case complexity with the worst case complexity isn't providing much insight into understanding the function's growth on either of the cases.
Whilst it is not wrong, it fails to provide more information than what we already know.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure of exactly what you're trying to ask, but bear in mind the below.

The typical algorithm used to show the difference between average and worst case running time complexities is Quick Sort with poorly chosen pivots.

On average with a random sample of unsorted data, the runtime complexity is `n log(n)`. However, with an already sorted set of data where pivots are taken from either the front/end of the list, the runtime complexity is `n^2`.